# How to 'copy' Conda environment to another machine after modifying some packages' source code?

Tags: conda, miniconda, anaconda3

I am trying to transfer to another computer. However, for my current project, I have made a lot of changes in different packages' source codes. I suspect using `conda env export > environment.yml` and `conda env create -f environment.yml` will not keep my modified codes.

Can I just copy the 'environment' folder to another machine? What is the best way to modify the packages' source codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [conda-pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/)?

Seems to solve exactly the problem you have.

Quote from the docs:

> A tool like conda-pack is necessary because conda environments are not relocatable. Simply moving an environment to a different directory can render it partially or completely inoperable. conda-pack addresses this challenge by building archives from original conda package sources and reproducing conda’s own relocation logic.